# How to print multiple arrays with foreach?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have 2 arrays: `post_titles` and `posts`. How do I print them one after another with `foreach`?

When I use 1 array, it works fine:

```
<?php foreach ($titles as $row) { ?>
    <?php echo $row['post_title'] ?> <br>                       
<?php } ?>
```

I want data to be printed like this:

```
Title
Post
<br>
Title
Post
<br>
```

etc.

Comment: I've tried your suggestions. Now I get  Array to string conversion message.

Comment: Use for - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: What's inside $post_titles and $posts?

Send the output of:
<?php
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($post_titles);
var_dump($posts);
echo "</pre>";
?>

Otherwise, it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each item in the titles and post correspond to each other (eg titles[1] and posts[1], titles[2] and posts[2]), you could use a `for` loop.
eg.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($titles); $i++) {
  echo $titles[$i];
  echo $posts[$i];
  echo "<br>";
}
```

or

```
  foreach ($titles as $i => $value ){  
        echo  $value  ." <br>" . $posts[$i] . " <br>";  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the array have the same index key you can use this

```
<?php
    foreach($titles as $key=> $value) {  
        echo  $value . ' - ' $post[$key] . '<br>';                     
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the 2 arrays are in sync i.e. the same length and arr1(0) equates to arr2(0) then its easy

```
<?php 
foreach ($post_titles as $i => $title) {
    echo $title . '<br>' . $posts[$i] . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I assumed that your other array was called `$posts` but use whatever the other array is called

Comment: Maybe you should show us an example of the 2 arrays you are using